# Can someone explain to me radix-sort?

Tags: sorting, radix-sort, array-algorithms

I am trying to implement radix-sort in javascript. However, I do not know how to do radix-sort! I have this pseudocode (from Introduction to Algorithms):

```
RADIX-SORT(A, d)
    for i = 1 to d
        use a stable sort to sort array A on digit i
```

however, when it says `A on digit i`, what is the meaning of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Radix sort, elements are sorted according to i^th digit. It starts sorting array A by looking at digit 1, then 2, ... upto digit d.

**For example: A = {423, 241, 732}**

> Iteration 1 (i=1): A = {24**1**,73**2**,42**3**}
>
> > Iteration 2 (i=2): A = {4**2**3,7**3**2,2**4**1}
> >
> > > Iteration 3 (i=3): A = {**2**41,**4**23,**7**32}  --sorted**

This takes linear time to sort an array of n elements (depends on the stable sort used inside). This does the sorting in O(n+d) time, where d is number of digits in an element.

And we could use any stable sort(counting sort or any other) to sort the elements.